# AJAX reload after edit omits non-BMP unicode characters

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, ajax, unicode

When editing a post that contains a non-BMP unicode character (codepoint U+10000 or up), the AJAX-loaded post when you submit the edit does not include that character.  I suspect this is a JSON-encoder bug on the server side.

For example, in my answer to [How to convert some character into five digit unicode one in Python 3.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624765/how-to-convert-some-character-into-five-digit-unicode-one-in-python-3-3/14625089#14625089), I included the codepoint U+1D15D ("MUSICAL SYMBOL WHOLE NOTE"), then was confused by the fact that not even a placeholder character was being shown.

Normally, the post looks like this:

[image: Placeholder glyph for U+1D15D]

(where the font used to render the glyph is missing that codepoint so a square box placeholder is shown instead).

When I edit the post the preview works fine, but when I then submit the edit the page is refreshed using AJAX and I see:

[image: Placeholder glyph gone]

There is no character between the quotes there; the JSON response for the edit gives me:

```
<pre><code>&gt;&gt;&gt; '\\U0001D15D'\n''\n&gt;&gt;&gt; '\\U0001D15D'.encode('unicode_escape')\nb'\\\\U0001d15d'\n</code></pre>\n\n
```

for that part of the post; again no U+1D15D character there.

Clearly, the SE software stack can handle non-BMP codepoints. The JSON standard can handle it too, almost all characters can be included literally, or you can use `\uabcd` escapes provided you encode these codepoints using a UTF-16 surrogate. See [section 2.5 of the JSON RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#page-4).

So, what I suspect is that non-BMP codepoints are not being handled by the JSON encoder on the server side and are instead silently dropped.

Can this be fixed?

Comment: Just tried it in the formatting sandbox. Was shown in the preview, vanished when submitting the edit.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Exactly, now reload the page..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an issue in ServiceStack.Text that [Kevin fixed a while ago](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/pull/244); looks like we didn't update the library afterwards. We'll use the newest version after the next build; I have checked that this does indeed fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the fix; that patch indeed removed a restriction where surrogates (e.g. non-BMP codepoints encoded to UTF-16) where filtered out.

Comment: Confirmed fixed; the AJAX response now includes the non-BMP codepoint.